# Converting a string to a recommendation type string

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text, text-classification

I am trying to build a recommendation system and some of the labels are

```
'printer has been replaced',
'scanner replaced',
'updated software to windows 10',
'password has been changed',
'monitor replaced',
'...'
```

What I want to do is convert these strings into more action item/ recommendation strings. Something like this

```
'I would recommend replacing the printer',
'I would recommend replacing the scanner',
'A software update to windows 10 is needed',
'I would recommend changing the password',
'I would recommend replacing the monitor'
'...'
```

Is there a library out there that does this? I have over a 1000 different resolution strings so the solution would need to be scalable.

Comment: I doubt there's any such library, it's not a standard NLP task.

Comment: @Erwan I didn't think there was either, just wanted to see if there are approaches people have done as I would assume this would be a typical problem others have worked on.

Comment: If anything that would be related to [Natural Language generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_generation) or simply Machine Translation, but it's clearly not worth deploying such a complex model for your use case. Btw why are the labels originally written like this? The easy solution would have been to write the labels like "replacing printer" in the first place, but it's probably too late for that!

Comment: @Erwan Yea I mean I will not deploy this live in production but I need to still change these strings to provide a recommendation instead of what the solution was if that makes sense.

Comment: If they are all following this kind of pattern, you could probably do it with a few regular expressions: ""X has been Yed" -> "Ying X", "Yed X" ->"Ying X", "X Yed" -> "Ying X". If these cases cover the majority you would have only a few outliers left to process manually.